# What is the best solder type in terms of health?

Tags: soldering

Hi im thinking of picking up a soldering iron and im wondering what type of solder is the best in terms of health

Comment: Wire Wrapping and Crimping is the best type of solder in terms of health

Comment: For mental health, lead based solder 63:37 Sn:Pb is a bit better.

Comment: Lead is just as safe for small scale use as lead free, for large scale manufacturing there is RoHS standards for PB-free, but even RoHS allows for lead based solder rework and touch up.

Comment: The hype about lead content is all politically motivated nonsense, so whatever lead-bearing alloy you choose will be benign in terms of your health and that of your peers and descendants.

Comment: The important thing with lead-based solder is to wash your hands after touching it. If your project is going to be a bare circuit board that people will put their hands all over, lead-free is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tin silver is ok. Just make sure you do any of this in a well ventilated area. Look for RoHS compliance lead-free solder if that is what you are asking. 
And don't eat it :)

Comment: Could you provide a link to buy tin-silver solder on amazon?

Comment: @craftxbox: No.  Shopping links go out-of-date quickly, and are [not welcome here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Only information that survives the passage of time.

Comment: Why can't you just log on to amazon and find out for yourselof?

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/soldering-desoldering-rework-products/solder/1310838?k=lead%20free%20solder